# PC is shutting off, but no crash logs

Tags: crash

So, my computer is shutting off, giving me a black screen (not the blue screen of death), and then attempt to power back or, which sometimes works and sometimes fails.

I've checked the windows crash logs, but nothing is reported, and I've downloaded a few 3rd party applications, but none of them are reporting crashes either.

When it does shut off, the motherboard still has power as the light remains on. There are no sounds associated with it, nor anything else out of the normal.

Comment: Open Control Panel, Security and Maintenance, and then run Reliability Monitor .  What Stop Errors are there that might shed some light.